# performance of parallel for loop

Tags: c#, multithreading

I need set the number of processor's threads for parallel "for-loop". I want work with only 3 threads of 8 (4-cores processor) ..... Now I'm using all 8 threads.

```
        System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(0, exponentstring.Length, (i, loopState) =>
        {
            int y = my_function (a, exponent[i], modulo);
            string str = y.ToString();
            if (str == numbers[0])
            {
                loopstop = 1;
                loopState.Stop();

            }

        });
```

Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: You didn't even check the overloads of `Parallel.For`, did you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an overload that takes an `ParallelOptions` object:

```
var options = new ParallelOptions();
options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3;
Parallel.For(0, exponentstring.Length, options, (i, loopState) =>
        {
...
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [ParallelOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class and set MaxDegreeOfParallelism